# Does 2FA security protect data stored on the back end?

Tags: multi-factor

I want to know how my data is protected if I enable 2FA on my account on the back end side.

I am using a MDM service to manage our company phones. My company works with sensitive data of clients. I want to be as secure as possible and to know the risks of using such a service.

Is the company able to access my account without my Google Auth 2FA tokens at all times or they can remove/reset it manually?

Does 2FA security offer some kind of encryption of my data and decrypt it when I enter the token?

Comment: "the company" -- what company? "access my account" -- what account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have some misconceptions.

2FA protects *authentication*. It does not protect the data on the back end from the service storing the data.

Can services turn on/off 2FA on the backend? Yes.

Can 2FA be used as an encryption key? Yes and no. That's a highly specialised use for the 2FA seed and services typically protect the encryption key with authentication, which can be protected by MFA.